# Java script call by reference

Tags: javascript

I have to call setTimeout() with parameter grpname,but initially it has not been declared but i want it to refer to the same value if change afterwords...

```
function test(grpname) {
    $('.middle').load("display.php", {
        "grpname": grpname
    });
}
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#inv').hide("fast");
        $('#t2').hide("fast");
        $('#username').click(function () {
            document.userid.username.value = "";
        });
        var grpname = document.userid.grpname.value;
        $('#signup').click(function () {
            $('#username').focus();
        });
        $('#signin').click(function () {
                var username = document.userid.username.value;
                setTimeout(test.bind(null, grpname), 1000);
                    ....
            }
```

Comment: So what's the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, primitive parameters are passed by value and object parameters are passed by reference. (https://snook.ca/archives/javascript/javascript_pass)

Observe this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8hkmysr1/8/

When the callback function runs, `param1` is unaffected by the change to the global value, as it was passed by value. `param2` is affected as it was passed by reference.

So you must either pass an object to the function so that the closure references the original object, or you must declare the variable in the global scope and read that value.